# Google +1 / StumbleUpon URL

Tags: facebook, google-plus

Facebook has the sharer page, twitter has it's own web intent page which lets you just redirect the user to their URLs and he can share/tweet something.

I've searched for something like that from Google +1 and StumbleUpon, and I haven't found anything. Isn't there something like `http://stumbleupon.com/submit?url=...` or the same for Google +1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed something like that for Google+1..

http://pc.mmgn.com/Articles/Batman-Arkham-City-Resonating-With-A-Sup

Check the side of that page, there is a little sidebar with a Google +1 stamp with a link to +1 it.. as well as the usual twitter, google, etc.

Here is the link for you:

http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/

Enjoy :)

Comment: you just beat me to it hazdog :)

Comment: haha no race here buddy, we're all trying to help so you're a winner too ;)

Comment: What I was looking for is rather something to help me build my custom G+1 button, so I would have my own button image and then with JavaScript just call a `window.open()` when the image was clicked. The problem is I don't know if there is an URL to +1 a site.

Comment: view the source of the frame of the +1 button in the first link in my original answer. you will see some code but perhaps more importantly, the URL is plusone.google.com/xxx. If you first used the default button and then just changed the image I'm sure you could make your own image link to the plus one. i will have a play around but i would not assume it to be impossible.

Comment: edit: i believe using a different image is against google's terms of service.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for RE: Google?

http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/